# Securing passwords SHA-1 Java

Tags: java, encryption, hash, cryptography, sha

I'm trying to securize the passwords of the web application I'm building. I'm pretty new to cryptography. I'm using Java and Sha-1 Hash to store the password in the Db.

After some research on the matter using a salt seems the best way to hash the passwords, but then  of course the salt has to be stored along with the password.

In my case I'm using a new column in the database for the salt, and I don't know if this is the right way to do it. If someone steals my database, with the hash and the salt will be able to read the password? Would it be better just to put a separator between the hash and the salt and store all together? In that case to check the validity of the password  I'd have to parse the string.
Just I would like to know your opinions and best practices that could apply here.

Thank you very much in advance!

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User implements BasePersistentEntity<Long> {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name="EMAIL",nullable=false,length=50,insertable=true,updatable=true)
private String email;

@Column(name="PASSWORD",nullable=false,length=40,insertable=true,updatable=true)
private String password;

@Column(name="SALT",nullable=false,length=40,insertable=true,updatable=true)
private String passwordSalt;


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email=email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    if (password.equals(this.password))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (passwordSalt == null || passwordSalt.equals(""))
    {
        passwordSalt = RandomStringUtils.randomAscii(20);
    }

    this.password = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(password + passwordSalt);
}

/**
 * Check if a given password is correct.
 *
 * @param givenPassword
 * @return True is correct, else false.
 */
public boolean checkPassword(String givenPassword)
{
    return (password.equals(DigestUtils.sha1Hex(givenPassword + passwordSalt)));
}


public String getPasswordSalt() {
    return passwordSalt;
}

public void setPasswordSalt(String passwordSalt) {
    this.passwordSalt = passwordSalt;
}
}
```

Comment: SHA1 is not secure.  Use scrypt or bcrypt or PBKDFv2.

Comment: Relevant: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/why-are-salted-hashes-more-secure

Comment: Also, you have at least two different questions here - "If someone steals my database with the salts, can they read the passwords?" (possibly better suited for security.se) and "Should I add a new column, or store two things in one column separated by `|`?"

Answer (score 1):

How the salt is stored is inconsequential to the security of the scheme. Both the salt and the hash can be stored in plain.

The salt can be used to prevent rainbow table attacks as well as for creating a different hash for identical passwords.

What you are however missing is some kind of work factor or iteration count. That is provided by Password Key Derivation Functions such as PBKDF2 (included in Java) or bcrypt. This would provide some additional protection against brute force attacks (trying all kinds of passwords and see if they match). This would add some security as passwords are usually lacking enough entropy.

It is possible to store a static "pepper" that can be combined with the salt in the server application. That may add some security if only the data gets stolen.

---

Example without pepper:

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;

public class PBKDF2ForPasswordHash {

    private static final String PBKDF_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
    private static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 10_000;
    // should be less than the size of the underlying hash
    private static final int PASSWORD_HASH_SIZE_BYTES = 16;
    private static final int SALT_SIZE_BYTES = 16;

    public static byte[] generateRandomSalt(final int saltSizeBytes) {
        final SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
        final byte[] salt = new byte[saltSizeBytes];
        rng.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }

    public static byte[] generatePasswordHash(final char[] password,
            final byte[] salt) {
        SecretKeyFactory f;
        try {
            f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBKDF_ALGORITHM);
        } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("PBKDF algorithm "
                    + PBKDF_ALGORITHM + " not available", e);
        }
        final KeySpec ks = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, ITERATION_COUNT,
                PASSWORD_HASH_SIZE_BYTES * Byte.SIZE);
        SecretKey s;
        try {
            s = f.generateSecret(ks);
        } catch (final InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "PBEKeySpec should always be valid for " + PBKDF_ALGORITHM,
                    e);
        }
        return s.getEncoded();
    }

    public static final String toHex(final byte[] data) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", data[i]));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final char[] password = { 'o', 'w', 'l' };
        final byte[] salt = generateRandomSalt(SALT_SIZE_BYTES);
        System.out.println(toHex(salt));
        final byte[] hash = generatePasswordHash(password, salt);
        System.out.println(toHex(hash));
    }
}
```

Comment: ummm plz dont store the password in the clear. Do you mean the hash of the password?

Comment: @stringy05 Must be getting late :)

Comment: ha ha. it's early where I am!

Comment: Anything missing from my answer or the answer of stringy05?

Comment: Iteration count should be higher - 86,000 apparently

Comment: Yes, true. The iteration count should be as high as you are willing to go for your system, 10K was the old default, today you should really use something 10 times as high. Even then, a good password will make more of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the salt next to the hash in the clear is fine, because the password is secure (provide you handle it with due care on your app - dont log it etc). The point of the salt is to have a unique input for the hash per user so you cant just use a rainbow table or guess the password (eg lots of users have the same hash then they are using the same password. I used to know the md5 hash of "password01" by heart due to a crappy wep app I had occasion to look at)

To find out how to do this properly refer to this: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/760/webapp-password-storage-salting-a-hash-vs-multiple-hashes as you need to ensure you are not susceptible to things like timing attacks (among a raft of other serious issues)

**EDIT**

For more detail about secure password storage, refer to this from the security ninjas at matasano http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2015/3/26/enough-with-the-salts-updates-on-secure-password-schemes.html

Answer (score 0):

It should be in my opinion more strongly noted that password hashing with salt is no longer secure and should not be used as others noted use PBKDF2 or bcrypt.

Comment: Although I'm glad you are concerned with security, I have to note that this is a comment, not an answer.